# Is Ghost Adventures real or fake?

Tags: reality-tv, ghost-adventures

I recently started watching *Ghost Adventures* and they seem real to me. But then I checked it on the web and found that it is a fake show. Some say it is fake, while others say it is real.

Still, I decided to check Wikipedia. I found that the show has "script" written by some crew member.

So, is this TV Series real or fake? If this is real, why it has "script"?

Comment: AFAIK, *all* 'reality' shows have some sort of script.

Comment: I neither believed or didn't believe until I saw a nylon string pulling Zac's shirt up in an episode where he was supposedly pulled on his shoulder by some "force"...I have to say I was surprised that they let that be seen on the video!!!
Ever since, I never watched it again.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1KuGUpHYDc

Comment: Let’s put it this way if any of this is “ghost” stuff is real why isn’t this the biggest news in the known world. They have just conclusively proved that there is a sort of life after death. Instead they are on the travel channel hawking terriblely stupid locations to visit.

Comment: @MarkD Right! It's probably staged to entice gullible audience and to create a different entertainment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crew member Aaron Goodwin spilled the beans back in 2014, which you can read more about [here](http://empirenews.net/ghost-adventures-star-gets-fired-reveals-disappointing-truth-about-paranormal-television-series/).

Basically he said that the crew (Zac, Nick, Aaron) strived for authenticity, but the Travel Network got in the way of that and forced fake reactions and other lies.  I would assume the "script" is indeed Travel Network-induced lines/reactions/etc. that they added because they thought it would make the show more exciting.

Comment: so all episodes of Ghost Adventures are not totally real? The EVPs, sightings/apparitions etc are all fake?

Comment: I can't seem to find the quote right now, but when Nick Groff left the show, he said something to the tune of "in the earlier seasons, it was real" but that the show lost its "realness" as things went on, it got more popular and Travel Channel got more ambitious.

Comment: Beware that the article linked in this accepted answer is itself fake, supposed "satire". Aaron was not fired from the show in 2014. See [this tweet from Aaron himself](https://mobile.twitter.com/aarongoodwin/status/495735508677701632).

Answer (score 1):

Source [BeforeItNews](http://beforeitsnews.com/paranormal/2014/01/ghost-adventures-cast-member-claims-no-fake-ghosts-2463106.html):

From Bishop James Long:

> Its no secret that I was on Ghost Adventures. I don’t advertise it,
>   its just there. I don’t work for Ghost Adventures, Sy Fy, The Travel
>   Channel or Bobby Mackeys and therefore, I am not going to be a walking
>   billboard and advertise for them. Period. If something happened, I
>   will report it. If nothing happened, I will report that as well. Thats
>   the wonderful thing about being able to speak freely about your
>   experience.
>
> I cannot speak about any other show but I CAN speak about the shows
>   that I have been on. I get a little upset when people constantly say
>   that every single Paranormal Show is scripted. Why? Because when
>   people say something like that, that implies that everyone who is ON
>   the show have been given a script and is aware that its fake and that
>   is rather offensive.
>
> 1. I have never been given a script for the Ghost Adventures shows that I have been on
> 2. I have NEVER been asked to fake evidence – if i were, i would tell the show, the hosts and the producers to jump off a cliff
> 3. I have not been paid for being on a show and so therefore, I am not an employee
> 4. I can, without hesitation, state that the activities that occurred at Bobby Mackeys did happen and that actually, the guys toned down
>      some of the things that they shared because it was a bit too personal.
>      I experienced things firsthand and can validate the things that
>      occurred while I was with them.
>
> it bothers me that people often give their “opinion” on this subject
>   matter and then they speak as if they are speaking facts. That is
>   misleading and unfair. If you were not on set, then how do you know
>   what is true and what is not? Opinions are NOT facts.
>
> If i watched a show that I was on and if i saw bullcrap, then I would
>   call it out. Period. For example, I was very vocal about the American
>   Haunting episode that I was on. I was very clear that there were
>   things that did not occur during the episode and that the directors
>   were rather adventurous with special affects; which ultimately ruined
>   the show for me. But, I was not the editor. I was asked to perform a
>   blessing on the home, which i did. Thats it.
>
> I can understand that people are skeptical with paranormal shows. I am
>   skeptical as well. But when people say that ALL paranormal shows are
>   fake and scripted, they need to stop and really pay attention to the
>   implication there. Are there shows that are scripted? I am sure. I am
>   just thankful that I have not had to waste my time with them.

Comment: I read that. But it conflicts with the other answer :(

Answer (score 0):

When they say "scripted" they are likely referring to in the beginning when they are explaining why the place is haunted and the history behind it and the voice overs. He's not going off the top of his head when he explains all of that stuff.

Comment: Welcome!  Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: Hello @Kat. I hope you are enjoying it here. Are you saying this a real show with "administrative" portions scripted for the sake of presentation on film? Please address the real/fake aspect of the question.